# Append values to a list

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Is there any way to add a list of numbers to a `List<int>` without using a loop?

My scenario:

```
List<int> test = CallAMethod();   // It will return a List with values 1,2

test = CallAMethod();             // It will return a List with values 6,8
```

But now the second set of values will replace the first set. Is there any way to append the values to the list without a for-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[List.AddRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

You'd need to do something like:

```
lst.AddRange(callmethod());
```

Alternatively,  C# 3.0, simply use 
[Concat](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-concat),

e.g.

```
lst.Concat(callmethod()); // and optionally .ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
test.AddRange(CallAMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

What about having the list as a parameter to CallAMethod, and adding items to it, instead of returning a new list each time?

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
CallAMethod(test); // add 1,2
CallAMethod(test); // add 6,8
```

Then you define CallAMethod as

```
void CallAMethod(List<int> list) {
    list.Add( /* your values here */ );
}
```